# how to add flutter plugin via git to another flutter project?

Tags: git, flutter

I want to add one flutter plugin in github as dependency to another flutter project.

i have followed the code 
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages#dependencies-on-unpublished-packages
and added a ref tag as mentioned here https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#git-packages

```
dependencies:
  mypluginname:
    git:
      url: http://mywebsite/myproject.git
      ref: master
```

i expect to fetch the latest commit of this branch(master), but it fetches first commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deleting the cache files in `flutter_sdk_install_directory/.pub_cache/git/my_project` and then doing `packages upgrade` on the flutter project worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Specifying the concrete commit like below helped me:

```yaml
dependencies:
  mypluginname:
    git:
      url: http://mywebsite/myproject.git
      ref: fad1b1dece2980dab850fc5128ae3c139963c0be
```

Answer (score 0):

you can

1. comment out the plugin in pubspec.yaml
2. run -> flutter packages get
3. uncomment and repeat step 2)

Answer (score 0):

To complete Tomas' answer. Use `path` field to point to a specific directory. Example:

```
dependencies:
  menubar:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding.git
      path: plugins/menubar
      ref: master
```

Run this `flutter pub get` to install it.